# How can I write maven build to add resources to classpath?

Tags: java, maven-3

I am building a jar using maven with simple maven install.
If I add a file to `src/main/resources` it can be found on the classpath but it has a config folder where I want that file to go but moving it inside the config folder makes it disappear from the classpath.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you place anything in `src/main/resources` directory, then by default it will end up in your final `*.jar`. If you are referencing it from some other project and it cannot be found on a classpath, then you did one of those two mistakes:

1. `*.jar` is not correctly loaded (maybe typo in the path?)
2. you are not addressing the resource correctly, for instance: `/src/main/resources/conf/settings.properties` is seen on classpath as `classpath:conf/settings.properties`

Comment: The URL protocol "classpath:" is specific to Spring.

Comment: Do I need to declare (via Spring @PropertySource for example) the location of the .properties file if it is not in the src/main/resources or, say,
in /src/main/resources/conf?
By default only src/main/resource files are put on the classpath or in any subdir too?
Thanks

Comment: Do I need to import /src/main/resources/application.properties in the first place (@PropertySource ("application.properties") or the default location does not need to be imported?

Answer (score 89):

A cleaner alternative of putting your config file into a subfolder of *src/main/resources* would be to enhance your classpath locations. This is extremely easy to do with Maven.

For instance, place your property file in a new folder *src/main/config*, and add the following to your pom:

```xml
 <build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/config</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
 </build>
```

From now, every files files under *src/main/config* is considered as part of your classpath (note that you can exclude some of them from the final jar if needed: just add in the build section:

```xml
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>my-config.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

so that *my-config.properties* can be found in your classpath when you run your app from your IDE, but will remain external from your jar in your final distribution).

Comment: +1 | Have a look at the reference documentation for this feature: http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Resources

Comment: I would take issue with this being "cleaner" but possibly, at least, a useful alternative in cases where the directory structure can't be modified.  Following the convention is always cleaner

Answer (score 9):

By default maven does not include any files from "src/main/java".

You have two possible way to that.

1. put all your resource files (different than java files) to "src/main/resources" - this is highly recommended
2. Add to your pom (resource plugin):

​

```
 <resources>
       <resource>
           <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
  </resources>
```