# How do I make mule persist my "src/test/resources" folder?

Tags: eclipse, maven, mule

I have mule configured as a maven project in eclipse and I reference some resources from the `src/test/resources`. However it seems like mule deletes these files when it is deployed onto mule server . How can I stop it from doing that?

**EDIT:**. Even if I were to persist it in src/main/resources.mule copies it to the root folder(classes) and doesnt actually create the src/main/resources folder . I have test cases that look against src/main(or test)/resources. How do I work around that?

Comment: can you look up for your resource using classpath:resourceName?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you want to persist src/test/resources - its against maven convention.

You should put your property files in src/main/resources folder instead. src/main/resources will be added to deployable archive.

Comment: As per maven convestion 'src/test/resources' folder should not be used beyond test phase so not sure why you want them later? That is the reason they dont show in archive. If you still want you can use additional classpath elements option in maven surefire plugin http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html

Answer (score 0):

src/test/resources is only used during the test phase of a Maven project. If you need resources within your deployment you need to place them in src/main/resources. Anything in src/main/resources should get copied to the classes folder of your Mule deployment archive.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: Right. Even if I were to persist it in src/main/resources. I believe mule copies it to the root of the folder and doesnt actually create the `src/main/resources` folder . I have test cases that look against `src/main(or test)/resources`. How do I work around that?

Comment: ok yes. you shouldn't reference src/main/resources directly. If your using Maven to build and run you should just be able to access them relatively.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this question is somewhat similar to your query(Not exactly same) but you might get an idea for the way forward
[How to can I make maven build add resources to classpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063296/how-to-can-i-make-maven-build-add-resources-to-classpath)