# Get the directory of the current file

Tags: java

I have two projects: A and B. Project B has a maven plugin, and when this is executed it should take some templates, which are resources of project A.

The templates are located in *C:/path/to/project/A/module1/src/main/resources/templates*.

The method that retrieves these templates uses velocity engine and the method is in a class located in *C:/path/to/project/A/module1/src/main/java*. I use the following path for the templates:

`String path = new File( "" ).getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "src" + File.separator + "main" + File.separator + "resources" + File.separator + "templates" + File.separator;`

In my unit tests this path is equal to *C:/path/to/project/A/module1/src/main/resources/templates*, but when I run the maven plugin from Project B, this path is equal to *C:/**path/to/project/B**/module1/src/main/resources/templates*. I realize this is because I launch from project B. I know if I put my templates in project B that it works but that's not what I want.

What I would like to achieve is to let the path always be equal to *C:/path/to/project/A/module1/src/main/resources/templates*. However, since other people are also using this project and their path to project A is most likely different from mine I cannot just do

`String path = "C:/path/to/project/A/module1/src/main/resources/templates"`.

So I would like to keep the first part in such a way that the path to project A is found, followed by "src/main/resources/templates". Is this possible and if yes, how?

**EDIT** To clarify: what I want is to get the path to project A from a method A1 that is inside project A. And this path to project A should also be found when I run method A1 from project B. The problem that I have with how I am retrieving the path right now is that when I run method A1 from project B then I get the path to project B.

**SOLUTION** It is working when I use the ClasspathResourceLoader (instead of the FileResourceLoader).

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `new File(""). + .. + .. +` thing can be simplified to `new File("src/main/resources/templates")`  - Java can deal with a `/` separator even if running on Windows

Comment: Does this need to actually be a filesystem file?  In general best practice for java is to reference things via classpath resources.  Answers to this question are relevant/useful:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063296/how-can-i-write-maven-build-to-add-resources-to-classpath

Comment: Are you asking how to find the path to project A, or how to add "src/main/resources/templates" to a path?

Comment: When you run methodA1 from project B, you are probably running a .class file stored in a jar file. It won't be the source directory.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException yes I think that is indeed the case. When I try PauMAVA's suggestion below, the path that I'm getting is the path to the jar file. Moreover, I see that my templates are inside this jar file as well. So I was thinking I might be able to access my templates in there if there is no easier way.

Comment: Yes, use the ClassLoader to access the templates from the jar file (get an InputStream to them).

Answer (score 1):

I did not completely unterstand your questions but getting dir-parts of a Path is possible when using class Path.

Have a look at

```
Path java.nio.file.Path.getName(int index)

int java.nio.file.Path.getNameCount()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that putting this into your project A class should do the trick:

```
String projectApath = MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
String path = projectApath + File.separator + "src" + File.separator + "main" + File.separator + "resources" + File.separator + "templates" + File.separator;
```

MyClass must be replaced by the class name where the method is in.

This will point to your Maven Local repository so you will have to export Project A with the templates, so that when you load it on Project B the templates will be extracted to your Local Maven Repo. This can be accomplished via ClasspathResourceLoader.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When I use this it is working for the unit tests but when I run the plugin from Project B, then I see the path is not my path to Project A anymore but a path in my maven repositories, so then it fails.

Comment: If I am not misunderstanding, the Project A path points to your local Maven repo as  you have imported it on Project B via Maven Dependency tools right? If that's the case, the only idea I have is that you pack the templates with the code so that when you import via Maven the templates are put into you Maven Local repo.

Comment: Yes that's correct. I packed the templates with the code and used the ClasspathResourceLoader to make it work.

Comment: Let me edit my answer, so that other users know how to approach this issue.