# Spring Boot - how to include src/main/resources sub-directory to classpath

Tags: spring-boot, classpath, maven-resources-plugin

I have file src/main/resources/**dev**/important.properties where in fact 'dev' is one of Spring profile names I use.
Somewhere in application this file is referenced as:

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:important.properties")
```

When I run in Intellij:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev
```

I get FileNotFoundException upon application start. If I move file one level up (to src/main/resources) it works. I can say no surprise here. **How to add src/main/resources/dev to classpath so this file would be visible in this directory?** This stuff is needed only for local development (Maven+Intellij and dev profile) and it's excluded from runnable jar. I do not want to modify `@PropertySource` expression.

Comment: This will fix your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9063515/13211030. However it does require your `@PropertySource` to be changed (also not sure why it's so important to keep this the way it is).